# React button with image with props

Tags: html, reactjs, image, react-props, react-component

now learning react and need to do some similar buttons with different images. 
my component:

```
export default class Button extends Component {
render() {
    return (

    <button className="header_btn"></button>
    )
}
```

}

How to set image to this button using props? Images saved in local storage

Answer (score 0):

**Hi please check this example:** Here I pass text and imageUrl as props.

```
import React from "react";

export default class Button extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <button className="header_btn">
                <img height="15px" width="15px" src={this.props.imageUrl} />
                {this.props.text}
            </button>
        )
    }
}
```

You should use Button Component in your App.js or any other component like below:

```
<Button text="Click" imageUrl="https://www.tutorialspoint.com/latest/inter-process-communication.png" />
```

Answer (score -2):

You can apply image on button using background: url('imageAddressInString');

```
<button style={background: `url(${this.props.imageUrl})`}></button>
```

and pass imageUrl to Button component in props.

```
const firstImage = './example.jpg';
<Button imageUrl={firstImage} />
```

Comment: compilator returns error: style={background: `url(${this where expected } instead :